# Convert a text field to a decimal number field in power bi

Tags: text, powerbi, type-conversion, fractions, decimalformat

I want to convert a column that appears to me as text that contains numbers with a decimal point to a field that will be a normal number so that I can sum up the column.

Columns that appeared to me as text and numbers were written in them I was able to convert to decimal numbers, but the column that is defined as a text type and contains numbers with a decimal point does not allow to convert to a decimal number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Power BI go to `Home -> Transform Data` and change type of column to decimal from text in Power Query

[image]